# Performance dependency on structure size

Tags: c, caching, operating-system

I have a structure like this

```
struct mystruct {
  /* used variables */
  /* cache line 1 */
  <variables>

  /* cache line 2 */
  <variables>

  ...

  /* unused variables */
  /* cache line n */
  <variables>
  /* cache line n+1 */
  <variables>
};
```

As shown above I have grouped variables, which are similar, into cache lines within the structure. There are also some unused variables (also grouped in cache lines), which will be used later.

Now I am using this structure like this

```
struct mystruct *foo = malloc(sizeoof(struct mystruct));

while (1) 
{
  /* access variables from used part only */
}
```

So as far as I know, as I am not accessing the variables of the unused part of the structure, those variables will never be cached. So, even if I store some unused variables in the structure, code performance should not degrade from if I had only stored the used variables.

Am I right?

Comment: Is this really a problem for you? Have you measured and profiled to make sure what you think is the bottleneck really is? It's not a case of premature optimization? And why have a structure with members you do not use? And what requirement or design rationale is there to create a structure so large that you have to worry about the CPU cache and performance due to its size?

Comment: And `malloc` will really allocate stack-aligned? There is no "unexpected alignment? ... too broad. Write your code to be most maintainable first. Then benchmark. If it **really** is too slow, profile then optimise the hotspots. Re-iterate.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have to use the unused variables in future, so they are there. Compiling out the unused part improves performance. I don't know if I can reduce the structure size (this is a packet metadata structure, somewhat like sk_buff of linux). Also, I am curious from theoretical aspect of the problem.

Comment: @Olaf Cache line size is 64 bytes. I have checked that malloc allocates the structure aligned to 64 byte boundary (which it should in normal case, as my structure is 64 byte aligned).

Comment: I don't see any alignnment specifiers. However, read the comments carefully again. And SO is not a discussion forum either. Write running code and maybe post this on code review, but read their FAQs first.

Comment: You mean `*foo`. Please post actual runnable code.

Comment: The code you have posted will have the same performance regardless of the size of the struct because it will never finish because you have an endless loop. What does "improves performance" mean? What do you measure? How do you measure it? Is your sample size big enough? How many of those structs do you allocate? Do you free them?

Comment: From the pure standpoint of a uniform cache line, yes, it should not impact performance provided those cold fields aren't being accessed. There could be other factors though that impact this like paging with a larger structure.